# Is there a way to get the Content-Length of HttpUriRequest before it gets sent in Android / Java?

Tags: java, android, http, httprequest

I want to have my Android app track its own data usage. I can get the Content-Length of the HTTP response, but I can't find how to get the size of the request before it's sent out. All the requests (GET, POST, PUT, etc) are instances of `HttpUriRequest`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All requests with content should be a subclass of `HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase`.

```
HttpUriRequest req = ...;
long length = -1L;
if (req instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase) {
    HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase entityReq = (HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase) req;
    HttpEntity entity = entityReq.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        // If the length is known (i.e. this is not a streaming/chunked entity)
        // this method will return a non-negative value.
        length = entity.getContentLength();
    }
}

if (length > -1L) {
    // This is the Content-Length. Some cases (streaming/chunked) doesn't
    // know the length until the request has been sent however.
}
```

Comment: All my requests come back as not an instance of HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase even if they are HttpPost or HttpPut originally. If I use a different if clause I receive a class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpUriRequest` class inherits from the `HttpRequest` class which has a method called `getRequestLine()`. You can call this function and call the `toString()` method and then the `length()` function to find the length of the request.

Example:

```
HttpUriRequest req = ...;
int reqLength = req.getRequestLine().toString().length());
```

This will get you the length of the `String` representation of the request.

Comment: The request-line is just the method, uri & version, e.g. `POST ./some/uri HTTP/1.1`