# Is there a way to find the full size of HTTP Request and response in Android (for data usage tracking)?

Tags: java, android, http, httprequest, httpresponse

i would like to track the data usage of my app, but to do that, I need to be able to get the full size of an `HttpUriRequest` and `HttpResponse`. Simply getting the size of the `HttpEntity` isn't enough because both the request and response have more data being transferred (headers, params, the actual URL being transmitted, etc). So, is there a way to find the full amount of data that's being transmitted both ways?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776302/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-content-length-of-httpurirequest-before-it-gets-sent-i

Comment: It's not -- that only got the size of the entity being transmitted, not the full request or response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want metrics "afterwards" you can just supply your own subclass of a suitable `ClientConnectionManager` implementation and fetch the relevant `HttpConnectionMetrics` after the request is returned to the manager.

As a simple (and slighty sh*tty) example, subclass `SingleClientConnManager`, like so:

```
class MeasuringClientConnManager extends SingleClientConnManager {
    private long mReceivedBytes = -1;
    private long mSentBytes = -1;
    public MeasuringClientConnManager(HttpParams params, SchemeRegistry schreg) {
        super(params, schreg);
    }
    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(ManagedClientConnection conn,
            long validDuration, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        HttpConnectionMetrics metrics = conn.getMetrics();
        mReceivedBytes = metrics.getReceivedBytesCount();
        mSentBytes = metrics.getSentBytesCount();
        metrics.reset();
        super.releaseConnection(conn, validDuration, timeUnit);
    }

    public long getReceivedBytes() {
        return mReceivedBytes;
    }
    public long getSentBytes() {
        return mSentBytes;
    }
}
```

and just cram it into your HTTP client like so:

```
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
SchemeRegistry schreg = new SchemeRegistry();
schreg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
// Add SSL here if you need it
MeasuringClientConnManager conman = new MeasuringClientConnManager(params, schreg);
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(conman, params);
client.execute(new HttpGet("http://www.google.com"));
System.out.println(conman.getSentBytes());
System.out.println(conman.getReceivedBytes());
```

**Edit**: Alternative example that uses logging session input & output buffers alongside a mangled wire log + adding a listener interface.

```
class MeasuringClientConnManager extends SingleClientConnManager {

    interface WireListener {
        void onUpdate(long sent, long recv);
    }
    private WireListener mListener;
    private long mReceivedBytes = -1;
    private long mSentBytes = -1;
    private Wire mWire = new Wire(null) {
        public boolean enabled() { return true; };
        // Time to override a bunch of methods (otherwise Wire will crash)
        public void input(byte[] b) throws IOException {mReceivedBytes += b.length; rxtx();};
        public void input(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {mReceivedBytes += len; rxtx();}
        public void input(InputStream instream) throws IOException {mReceivedBytes += count(instream); rxtx();}
        public void input(String s) throws IOException {mReceivedBytes += s.length(); rxtx();};
        public void input(int b) throws IOException {mReceivedBytes++; rxtx();}
        public void output(byte[] b) throws IOException {mSentBytes += b.length; rxtx();}
        public void output(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {mSentBytes += len; rxtx();}
        public void output(int b) throws IOException {mSentBytes++; rxtx();}
        public void output(String s) throws IOException {mSentBytes += s.length(); rxtx();}
        public void output(InputStream outstream) throws IOException {mSentBytes += count(outstream); rxtx();};

        private int count(InputStream is) throws IOException {
            int result = 0;
            byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 8];
            int count;
            while ((count = is.read(b)) > -1) {
                result += count;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };

    public MeasuringClientConnManager(HttpParams params, SchemeRegistry schreg) {
        super(params, schreg);
    }

    public void setWireListener(WireListener wl) {
        mListener = wl;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionOperator createConnectionOperator(
            SchemeRegistry schreg) {
        final ClientConnectionOperator actual = super.createConnectionOperator(schreg);
        ClientConnectionOperator wired = new ClientConnectionOperator() {
            @Override
            public void updateSecureConnection(OperatedClientConnection conn,
                    HttpHost target, HttpContext context, HttpParams params)
                    throws IOException {
                actual.updateSecureConnection(conn, target, context, params);
            }
            @Override
            public void openConnection(OperatedClientConnection conn, HttpHost target,
                    InetAddress local, HttpContext context, HttpParams params)
                    throws IOException {
                actual.openConnection(conn, target, local, context, params);
            }

            @Override
            public OperatedClientConnection createConnection() {
                DefaultClientConnection conn = new DefaultClientConnection() {
                    @Override
                    protected SessionInputBuffer createSessionInputBuffer(
                            Socket socket, int buffersize, HttpParams params)
                            throws IOException {
                        return new LoggingSessionInputBuffer(super.createSessionInputBuffer(socket, buffersize, params), mWire);
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected SessionOutputBuffer createSessionOutputBuffer(
                            Socket socket, int buffersize, HttpParams params)
                            throws IOException {
                        return new LoggingSessionOutputBuffer(super.createSessionOutputBuffer(socket, buffersize, params), mWire);
                    }
                };
                return conn;
            }
        };
        return wired;
    }

    void rxtx() {
        WireListener l = mListener;
        if (l != null) {
            l.onUpdate(mSentBytes, mReceivedBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is very similar, but now with wire updates as stuff is sent:

```
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
SchemeRegistry schreg = new SchemeRegistry();
schreg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
// Add SSL here if you need it
MeasuringClientConnManager conman = new MeasuringClientConnManager(params, schreg);
conman.setWireListener(new MeasuringClientConnManager.WireListener() {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(long sent, long recv) {
        System.out.println("WIRE sent: " + sent + ", recv: " + recv);
    }
});
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(conman, params);
client.execute(new HttpGet("http://www.thirdbase.se"));
```

Comment: that looks great, but i have a question -- the data size gets counted only when the connection is released. Any way to have it counted while it's active? I'm using a ThreadSafeAConnectionManager, and I'm not sure how often the connections get released

Comment: You mean like supplying it with a listener that is updated whenever something is written on the wire? If we were dealing with a "normal" Apache HTTP client installation you would've been able to mess with the `org.apache.http.impl.Wire` class - but that has an unfulfilled reference to the Apache commons logging package - which isn't part of the SDK apparently. Never tried that on Android.

Comment: @user496854 - well, that wasn't very hard actually. updated the example with a crappy impl. of a listener interface + Wire log.