# Why was this change made to SocketInputBuffer for Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: android, apache

Can anyone help me understand this "fix":

https://www.gitorious.org/rowboat/external-apache-http/commit/e30b5b55806b31d1a61e2885b854dd7b8da1a07a

It's causing my motion jpeg (mjpg, mjpeg) code to slow way down as I'm reading the jpg images.  The fix seems horrible to me, completely ignoring the passed parameter and therefore giving the caller no chance to adjust the value.

Is there a way to work-around the change so that I can use a larger buffer size?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10789884/967142) shows how to replace the session input buffer (in this case for logging), refer to the overrides of `protected SessionInputBuffer createSessionInputBuffer`.

Answer (score 2):

From the commit log:

> Make Apache HttpClient play nice with large kernel socket buffers.
>
> Given the large maximum size likely to be set for kernel socket
>   buffers on LTE devices, we need to stop Apache HttpClient from
>   allocating some integer multiple of that size on the heap for each
>   socket. On one device, 16 HTTP connections would fill the heap.

This basically means that Android doesn't trust LTE devices to set their own buffer size, because it would fill the heap too quickly.

As a workaround, try extending the `AbstractSessionInputBuffer` to create your own version of the `SocketInputBuffer` class.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround suggestion.  I may try that, but it looks like it could get pretty complicated.  I'm making a call to DefaultHttpClient::Execute() which takes me through about a dozen calls and finally into the SocketInputBuffer() constructor.  It seems as though I'd have to copy several classes into my project to get it done since I don't think I can simply override functions along the way.  And now I'm at the point that any changes to those classes for the better are missed by me since I'm no longer using them.  I wish there were a simple hook into that code.